# Display text on tooltip when hover over Doughnut chart in JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, plugins, chart.js

*Here is the code. I am new in Js. I want to display text with data on tooltip when we hover on the doughnut without active the labels mentioned in datasets*

```js
const data = {
  //labels: ['xyz', 'abc'],
  datasets: [{
   label: 'Weekly Sales',
    data: [12, 20],     
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgb(254, 214, 10)',
      'rgb(255, 90, 48)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
      "#ffffff",         
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

var sum = 0;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < data.datasets[0].data.length; ++i) {
    sum += data.datasets[0].data[i];
}
console.log("sume", sum);
 for (i = 0; i < data.datasets[0].data.length; ++i) {
    data.datasets[0].data[i] = Math.round((data.datasets[0].data[i] / sum) * 100); 
}  

// config 
const config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data,
    options: {
    plugins: {
     datalabels: {
                        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
                let datasets = ctx.chart.data.datasets;
                
                      if (datasets.indexOf(ctx.dataset) === datasets.length - 1) {
                       //var sum = datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
                       var percentage = Math.round((value / sum) * 100) +"%";
                      return percentage;
                    
                     } else {
                       return percentage;
                     
     }


      },
      color: '#fff',
            }
     }
    }        
  }; 


// render init block
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#count1").text( data.datasets[0].data[0]+"%" );
$("#count2").text( data.datasets[0].data[1]+"%" )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4"></script>
<!--  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>  -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

<div class="block-text">
             <div class="flex-chart"> <div class="box-file"></div><p class="spacing">abc</p>
             <p id = "count1">20%</p></div>

             <div class="flex-chart"> <div class="box-url"></div><p class="spacing">xyz</p> 
             <p id = "count2">30%</p>

         </div>
         </div>
```

As you can see in the code. I have commented the label heading (//labels: ['xyz', 'abc']) without uncommenting this line, I just want text in replace of undefined on tooltip when I'll hover on Doughnut Chart in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the tooltip callback for this:

```js
tooltips: {
  callbacks: {
    label: (ctx, data) => (`Some text: ${data.datasets[ctx.datasetIndex].data[ctx.index]}`)
  }
},
```

Live sample:

```js
const data = {
  //labels: ['xyz', 'abc'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Weekly Sales',
    data: [12, 20],
    backgroundColor: [
      'rgb(254, 214, 10)',
      'rgb(255, 90, 48)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
      "#ffffff",
    ],
    borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

var sum = 0;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < data.datasets[0].data.length; ++i) {
  sum += data.datasets[0].data[i];
}
console.log("sume", sum);
for (i = 0; i < data.datasets[0].data.length; ++i) {
  data.datasets[0].data[i] = Math.round((data.datasets[0].data[i] / sum) * 100);
}

// config 
const config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data,
  options: {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (ctx, data) => (`Some text: ${data.datasets[ctx.datasetIndex].data[ctx.index]}`)
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: (value, ctx) => {
          let datasets = ctx.chart.data.datasets;
          if (datasets.indexOf(ctx.dataset) === datasets.length - 1) {
            //var sum = datasets[0].data.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
            var percentage = Math.round((value / sum) * 100) + "%";
            return percentage;
          } else {
            return percentage;
          }
        },
        color: '#fff',
      }
    }
  }
};


// render init block
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#count1").text(data.datasets[0].data[0] + "%");
  $("#count2").text(data.datasets[0].data[1] + "%")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4"></script>
<!--  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0"></script>  -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.0.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

<div class="block-text">
  <div class="flex-chart">
    <div class="box-file"></div>
    <p class="spacing">abc</p>
    <p id="count1">20%</p>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-chart">
    <div class="box-url"></div>
    <p class="spacing">xyz</p>
    <p id="count2">30%</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Chart.js` version `2.9.4` but the synytax is of version `3.x`. If you the latest `Chart.js` version (`3.8.2` as of right now), code works just fine.

Here's your example: https://jsfiddle.net/zkx5acuv/5/

Comment: I don't want to change the chart js version ...  please help me to work this in this version if possible

Comment: I've tried it with version `2.9.4` and it looks like the code works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jw1qtp9z/4/

Except I used `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` version `0.7.0`.

Comment: Dear Sir @IvanTsenilov, I think u didn't follow my answer. My question is just to show text and percentage value on tooltip when hover over chart. (e.g: count: 48). Kidnly don't label percentage on chart I don't need this

Comment: Dear @Ivan Tsenilov, dont uncomment label. e.g: //labels: ['xyz', 'abc']. I want text without uncommenting labels tag. e.g(count: 20) like this